# ECG: vector perpendicular to lead axis and its pattern

Tags: cardiology, electrocardiogram

I have come across a contradiction while learning about ECG.

Some sources say that a **biphasic deflection** (two waves of same size but of opposite directions) is drawn on ECG tracing if the electrical vector is **perpendicular** to electrical axis of lead.

[image: Biphasic deflection]

Other sources say that an **isoelectric line** is drawn on ECG tracing if the electrical vector is perpendicular to electrical axis of lead.

[image: Isoelectric line]

Which statement is correct?

Answer (score 0):

I only have basic knowledge in heart electrophysiology. Nonetheless, I think that the main principle is just the projection of the vector on the lead and then evaluating its length. Following this logic, we get that a perpendicular vector is equal to 0 (isoelectric line) which is the only case where we could say it is zero. and if you take the case 'd' and think of it as two vectors then their sum is a perpendicular vector as well (but they aren't isoelectric). Thus I think that the biphasic deflection takes into account the temporal aspect of the vector change and how it passes from one state to another.
I just wanted to share my line of thinking and I hope that it may serve to ease some of the confusion though I can't ascertain the righthood of this answer.

[image]